# Узнать координаты мыши относительно блока

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: надо получить координаты мыши относительно блока, на котором она находится.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
  console.log(`${x}:${y}`);
}, {
  capture: true
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>daw</div>
```

Пытался так, но понятно дело, что не получилось.

---

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: присмотритесь к методу `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: мой ответ с `getBoundingClientRect` -- ниже

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы получить координаты внутри элемента, нужно из абсолютных координат мыши ([pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY), [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX)) вычесть смещение самого элемента. Получить его можно с помощью методов [`.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) и [`.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

```js
let div = document.querySelector('#f');

div.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let x = e.pageX,
    y = e.pageY;

  console.log(`${x - div.offsetLeft}:${y-div.offsetTop}`);
}, {
  capture: true
})
```

```css
div#a {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}

div#f {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="f">daw</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "topPos is the number of pixels from the top of the closest relatively positioned parent" -- если в  оно внутри relative -- не сработает

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, для данного примера - это не важно

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос по поводу твоего ответа, как исправить отрицательные координаты? Добавил скриншот в вопрос

Comment: @Voprositel, а зачем их исправлять? В добавок к рисунку добавь в вопрос и разметку со стилями и кодом, для которой можно получить подобные результаты

Comment: @Grundy, мне нужны координаты от верхнего левого угла начиная с нуля для вычислений, хотя, возможно я просто не догоняю

Comment: @Grundy, отмена тревоги, все хорошо, мне так и надо было) Спасибо.

Comment: @Voprositel, если быстро двигаешь мышкой mousemove может не всегда успевать, поэтому может брать координаты до того как курсор зашел над элементом, поэтому при вычитании могут получаться отрицательные значения.

Comment: @Grundy, в данной ситуации блок был похож на координатное поле, но мне, оказывается, так и надо было, поэтому все хорошо

Comment: @Grundy, добавил вариант на случай, если кому-то важно

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на `getBoundingClientRect` и `event.clientX`, который не зависит от `relative`.

`offsetLeft` считается от ближайшего предка с `position relative`.

У `clientX` и `pageX` разное поведение при скроле.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> позиция мыши </title>
<style>

div#a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
div#b {
  position: relative;
}
div#f {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"><div id="b"><div id="f">0</div></div></div>
<script>

const div = document.querySelector('#f');
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(` + ${ev.clientX - rect.left}:${ev.clientY - rect.top}    ----------    ${ev.pageX - div.offsetLeft}:${ev.pageY - div.offsetTop}`);
}, {
  capture: true
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: поправь пример, чтобы разница была видна

Comment: я имел ввиду, стили, чтобы было видно, что в одном случае одно значение показывает, а в твоем другое

Comment: ты пишешь _вариант, который не зависит от relative_ - и в примере ни одного relative

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('.class').addEventListener('mousemove',e=>console.log([e.toElement,e.offsetX])) // console.log

document.querySelector('.class').addEventListener('mousemove',e=>{e.toElement.className == document.querySelector('.class').className ? console.log(e.offsetX) : false})

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]